# Create an Array of Fixed Length Given an Array of Arbitrary Length

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm looking to write a method that creates an array of a fixed length (in my case 12) from any array it is provided of arbitrary length (though the length will always be 12 or less) by repeating the objects in order.

So for example given the array a:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I would want to have returned:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Another example:

```
b = ["peach", "plumb", "pear", "apple", "banana", "orange"]
```

Would return:

```
b = ["peach", "plumb", "pear", "apple", "banana", "orange", "peach", "plumb", "pear", "apple", "banana", "orange"]
```

And so on. If given an array with 12 objects, it would just return the same array.

The methods I've written to accomplish this so far have been very ugly and not very Rubyish; interested in how others would handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In 1.8.7 & 1.9 you can do cool stuff with [Enumerators](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Enumerable.html)

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
#=> [1,2,3,4]
a.cycle.take 12
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: did not know that--very nice.

Comment: Very nice. FOr Ruby 1.8.6, just `require 'backports'`

Comment: Wow, would have never known about this. Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

```
Array.new(12).fill(some_array).flatten[0..11]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def twelvify array
  array += array while array.size < 12
  array[0..11]
end
```

It's also a bit ugly but it's, at least, simple. :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is definitely a cleaner version of what I was coming up with.

Comment: I love that the method is called `:twelvify` :)

Comment: *chuckle* Yep, I definitely got a good Rubyish name for it, but I have to admit that I like BarqueBobcat's answer a lot more than mine! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
array * (12/array.size) + array[0, (12 % array.size)]
```

Comment: Exactly what the OP asked for, but dear $deity it's ugly :)

Comment: How about: array * (12/array.size + 1))[0,12]

Comment: @sepp2k, did you mean ... instead of ..?